# How do I fix find_by(remember_token: remember_token)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, token

I am in chapter 8 of the rails tutorial by Michael Hardtl.  I've gone through this code a ton of times and seen some similar questions on stackoverflow, but none have helped.  I am trying to make a simple signin page.  I am pretty sure something is wrong with the line

```
@current_user ||= User.find_by(remember_token: remember_token)
```

I have tried using the find_by method before and it does not work.  It usually works if i append an _ to find_by and then what I am looking for like this:

```
@current_user ||= User.find_by_remember_token(remember_token)
```

but that is not working either.  Here is my full code below.  Thank you to whomever can help me!

```
module SessionsHelper
    def sign_in(user)
        remember_token = User.new_remember_token
        cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = remember_token
        user.update_attribute(:remember_token, User.encrypt(remember_token))
        self.current_user = user
    end

    def current_user=(user)
        @current_user = user
    end

    def current_user
        remember_token = User.encrypt(cookies[:remember_token])
        @current_user ||= User.find_by(remember_token: remember_token) #The find_by method might not work
    end

    def signed_in?
        !current_user.nil?
    end
end
```

This is what my browser says when I try to open the page:

```
NoMethodError in Static_pages#home

Showing /Users/philip7899/rails/sample_app/app/views/layouts/_header.html.erb where line #9 raised:

undefined method `find_by' for User(Table doesn't exist):Class
```

Comment: Are you sure you are running on rails 4?

Comment: I am not running rails 4. I'm using 3.2.12 - Im still learning rails and Im afraid to upgrade and accidentally ruin everything Im working on now.  It was my understanding that in the version of rails Im using that instead of find_by(thingiwanttofind) I should be able to type find_by_thing_i_want_to_find.

Comment: Silly question, but, do you have a users table?

Comment: probably a db migration issue...does `User.find_by_name` work?

Comment: I have a users table.  I'm pretty sure its not a migration issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

think the rails tutorials book assumes that you are running on rails 4 and in rails 4 all the dynamic finders have been deprecated . Since you are running on 3.2 ,the way for you to go is

`@current_user ||= User.where( remember_token : remember_token ).first`

Comment: Thanks, I tried that.  The browser says: undefined method `model_name' for ActiveRecord::Relation:Class

Comment: then it says: Extracted source (around line #16):

13:                 Account <b class="caret"></b>
14:               </a>
15:               <ul class="dropdown-menu">
16:                 <li><%= link_to "Profile", current_user %></li>
17:                 <li><%= link_to "Settings", '#' %></li>
18:                 <li class="divider"></li>
19:                 <li>

Comment: I can't figure out how to use code in the comments.  I apologize for the bad formatting.

Comment: can you try User.where( remember_token : remember_token ).first

Comment: Also make sure that your migrations ran fine and iyour users table has ll the columns as expected

Comment: That worked!  Thank you!  I am not sure I understand why though.  Would you mind explaining why .first is needed?  Shouldn't it work without .first?

Comment: The form expects a single record to be in the @current_user instance variable, the where-method doesn't return a single record but a relation, which can be multiple records, once queried. So by doing first you are getting the record and not the relation

Comment: Thanks.  What do you mean returns a relation?  Does that means returns an array?

Comment: Right. its returns an array of records